# How to get payload in component in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './search.styles.scss';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { setSearchField } from '../../redux/search/search.actions';
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

    class Search extends React.Component{
        render(){
            const { onSetSearchField, search } = this.props;
            return (
                <div className="search-container">
                <p>user: {search}</p>
                    <input className="search-box" type="text" onChange={onSetSearchField} />
                </div>
            )
        }
    } 

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            onSetSearchField: (event) => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value))
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        console.log(state.search, "-----------")
        if(state.search === "user:"){
            alert(state.search)
        }
        return {
            search: state.search
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```

reducer:

```
    const initialStateSearch = {
        search: null
    }

    export const getSearchType = (state=initialStateSearch, action={}) => {
        switch (action.payload) {
            case 'user':
                return Object.assign({}, state, {search: action.payload})
            case 'post':
                return Object.assign({}, state, {search: action.payload})
            default:
            return state
        }
    }
```

action:

```
    import { SearchActionTypes } from './search.types';

        export const setSearchField = (text) => ({
            type: SearchActionTypes.SEARCH_START,
            payload: text
        })
```

Here I'm adding search functionality using react and redux 
But when I'm checking my payload in the reducer. It is coming but it is not coming in my search component.

I am alerting and trying to alert and display the text on a p tag

Please have a look

Comment: Honestly, I'm pretty stumped, because your code looks fine. So, does `console.log(state.search, "-----------")` print the search state?

Comment: no. only redux-logger is coming

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment to your question, the code you showed for your component and redux looks fine, and the fact that you can see your redux store being populated makes me believe the problem lies with the configuration.

Have you tried making sure the `Provider` is a wrapper at the root level, so the components will know about the redux store https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider? If that exists, then I would advise looking at the redux example https://codesandbox.io/s/9on71rvnyo online and try to follow there logic and see what potentially you could be missing.

Comment: when i am adding alert in my reducer it is coming. But not coming in Mapstateto props() inside component

Comment: "But not coming in Mapstateto props() inside component" - so I do think it something happening at the root level of your redux configuration, potentially with a non-working `Provider` as per my comment!

Comment: Okk . i will see

Comment: okay good luck :) - also, looking at the code sandbox example will really help!

Comment: Worked  Was issue in root reducer

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if you have used the same constant in Action Creator setSearchField for which you are checking in reducer. Is SearchActionTypes.SEARCH_START === 'user' or 'post'.